# Python Pandas: Calculating transaction count and transactions with multiple sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a DataFrame in Python using the Pandas library and I need help with calculating some metrics. I have a DataFrame with the following columns: WEBSHOP_ORDER, CLASS, USIM, USIM_DESC, SIZE, and DEMAND_QTY.

My goal is to calculate two metrics for specific USIMs (product IDs):

Transaction_Count: The number of unique transactions (WEBSHOP_ORDER) for each USIM.
transaction_with_Multiple_Sizes: The number of transactions for each USIM that have multiple sizes.
I've tried using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame

# Define the list of specific USIMs
usims_of_interest = [2199603, 2199608, 2199611, 2199641, 2199642, 2199682, 2199692, 2199697, 2200982]

# Generate random sample data
np.random.seed(0)
size_choices = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'WEBSHOP_ORDER': np.random.randint(1, 10001, 10000),
    'CLASS': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 10000),
    'USIM': np.random.choice(usims_of_interest, 10000),
    'USIM_DESC': ['Product {}'.format(i) for i in np.random.randint(1, 10001, 10000)],
    'SIZE': np.random.choice(size_choices, 10000),
    'DEMAND_QTY': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10000)
})
#df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/file.csv')

# Define the list of specific USIMs
usims_of_interest = [2199603, 2199608, 2199611, 2199641, 2199642, 2199682, 2199692, 2199697, 2200982]

# Filter the DataFrame for the specific USIMs
filtered_df = df[df['USIM'].isin(usims_of_interest)]

# Group by USIM and calculate the required metrics
grouped = filtered_df.groupby('USIM').agg(
    Transaction_Count=('WEBSHOP_ORDER', 'nunique'),
    transaction_with_Multiple_Sizes=('USIM', lambda x: (x.duplicated() & x.notna()).sum())
).reset_index()

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(grouped)
```

However, the calculation for transaction_with_Multiple_Sizes seems to be incorrect. It yields values greater than Transaction_Count, which is not logically possible.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly calculate the transaction_with_Multiple_Sizes metric based on the conditions mentioned. Is there a more appropriate approach or modification to my code that can address this issue?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Same difficulty as before that for `Transaction_Count` you only need to group by `USIM`, but for `transaction_with_Multiple_Sizes` you need to group by both `USIM` and `WEBSHOP_ORDER`.

The solution below first groups on both `USIM` and `WEBSHOP_ORDER`, then takes the output of that and groups on just `USIM`. I think this should be fast and should give the output you need.

Since you're asking for multiple operations regarding the number of orders per size, I think it makes sense to create the intermediate table with columns of the counts of each size per USIM/ORDER

Thanks again for making such an easily reproducible example!

```
# Pivot to create table of USIM/ORDER with the number of orders of each size
sizes_per_order = filtered_df.pivot_table(
    index = ['USIM','WEBSHOP_ORDER'],
    columns = 'SIZE',
    values = 'DEMAND_QTY',
    aggfunc = 'count',
    fill_value = 0,
)

#Add "summary" columns based on the numbers of orders of each size per USIM/ORDER
#'multiple_sizes_in_transaction' is True if more than one column of Large/Medium/Small is > 0 per row
#Similarly, at least one column of Large/Medium/Small > 1 for transactions with duplicate sizes
sizes_per_order = sizes_per_order.assign(
   multiple_sizes_in_transaction = sizes_per_order.gt(0).sum(axis=1).gt(1),
   duplicate_sizes_in_transaction = sizes_per_order.gt(1).any(axis=1),
)

print(sizes_per_order)

#Groupby the USIM, which is the level=0 index
usim_grouped = sizes_per_order.groupby(level=0).agg(
    Transaction_Count=('multiple_sizes_in_transaction', 'count'),
    transactions_with_Multiple_Sizes=('multiple_sizes_in_transaction', 'sum'),
    transactions_with_Duplicate_Sizes=('duplicate_sizes_in_transaction', 'sum'),
)

print(usim_grouped)
```

**Intermediate table that has the count of sizes per USIM/ORDER**

We've also added the "summary" columns of "multiple" and "duplicate" sizes per order to this table

[image]

**Final table**

[image]

Note that it's possible for a USIM/ORDER to be both "multiple" and "duplicate" like these rows of the intermediate table:

[image]

Comment: There are some transactions where the same size was bought multiple times as well. can we please edit the solution to add those transactions as well? #transaction_with_same_Sizes

Comment: @sdave Edited the answer. Also made an intermediate table that should allow you to ask other "summary" questions about the counts of each size in each order